syntax error messages "not terminated" and "unexpected END-IF"
I'm having a constant issue with the UPDATE-PRODUCT portion. I'm getting an error at Line 103:

PERFORM statement not terminated by END-PERFORM

and at Line 117:

syntax error, unexpected END-IF.

       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID. Inventory-Management.
       DATA DIVISION.
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
         01 PRODUCT.
           05 ITEM-CODE       PIC X(5).
           05 NAME            PIC X(20).
           05 PRICE           PIC 9(5)V99.
           05 QUANTITY        PIC 9(5).
    
         01 CHOICE             PIC X.
         01 ITEM-FOUND         PIC X VALUE 'N'.
    
         01 INVENTORY.
           05 ITEM-CODE-LIST  OCCURS 100 TIMES.
               10 ITEM-CODE-ARRAY PIC X(5).
           05 NAME-LIST        OCCURS 100 TIMES.
               10 NAME-ARRAY     PIC X(20).
           05 PRICE-LIST       OCCURS 100 TIMES.
               10 PRICE-ARRAY    PIC 9(5)V99.
           05 QUANTITY-LIST    OCCURS 100 TIMES.
               10 QUANTITY-ARRAY PIC 9(5).
           05 NUM-OF-PRODUCTS  PIC 99 VALUE 0.
    
         01 ITEM-CODE-SEARCH    PIC X(5).
         01 NEW-PRODUCT.
           05 NEW-NAME         PIC X(20).
           05 NEW-PRICE        PIC 9(5)V99.
           05 NEW-QUANTITY     PIC 9(5).
    
         01 ITEM-INDEX          PIC 99.
    
         01 DEL-ITEM-CODE       PIC X(5).
    
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       MAIN-PROGRAM.
       PERFORM WELCOME-SCREEN.
       PERFORM UNTIL CHOICE = '5'
           PERFORM DISPLAY-MENU
           ACCEPT CHOICE
           PERFORM PROCESS-CHOICE
       END-PERFORM.
           STOP RUN.
    
       WELCOME-SCREEN.
           DISPLAY "WELCOME TO INVENTORY LIST MANAGEMENT".
           DISPLAY "1. Insert New Product".
           DISPLAY "2. Search Product Info".
           DISPLAY "3. Update Product".
           DISPLAY "4. Delete Product".
           DISPLAY "5. Exit".
    
       DISPLAY-MENU.
           DISPLAY "Please select an option:".
    
       PROCESS-CHOICE.
           EVALUATE CHOICE
               WHEN '1' PERFORM INSERT-PRODUCT
               WHEN '2' PERFORM SEARCH-PRODUCT
               WHEN '3' PERFORM UPDATE-PRODUCT
               WHEN '4' PERFORM DELETE-PRODUCT
               WHEN '5' CONTINUE
               WHEN OTHER DISPLAY "Invalid choice. Please select again."
           END-EVALUATE.
    
       INSERT-PRODUCT.
           DISPLAY "Enter Product Name:".
           ACCEPT NEW-NAME.
           DISPLAY "Enter Item Code:".
           ACCEPT ITEM-CODE.
           DISPLAY "Enter Price:".
           ACCEPT NEW-PRICE.
           DISPLAY "Enter Quantity:".
           ACCEPT NEW-QUANTITY.
    
           ADD 1 TO NUM-OF-PRODUCTS
           MOVE ITEM-CODE TO ITEM-CODE-LIST(NUM-OF-PRODUCTS)
           MOVE NEW-NAME TO NAME-LIST(NUM-OF-PRODUCTS)
           MOVE NEW-PRICE TO PRICE-LIST(NUM-OF-PRODUCTS)
           MOVE NEW-QUANTITY TO QUANTITY-LIST(NUM-OF-PRODUCTS).
    
       SEARCH-PRODUCT.
           DISPLAY "Enter Item Code to search:".
           ACCEPT ITEM-CODE-SEARCH.
           PERFORM VARYING ITEM-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL ITEM-FOUND = 'Y' OR ITEM-INDEX > NUM-OF-PRODUCTS
           IF ITEM-CODE-SEARCH = ITEM-CODE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
            DISPLAY "Product Found:"
            DISPLAY "Item Code: " ITEM-CODE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
            DISPLAY "Name: " NAME-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
            DISPLAY "Price: " PRICE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
            DISPLAY "Quantity: " QUANTITY-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
            MOVE 'Y' TO ITEM-FOUND
           END-IF
       END-PERFORM.
           IF ITEM-FOUND = 'N'
               DISPLAY "Product not found."
           END-IF.
    
       UPDATE-PRODUCT.
           DISPLAY "Enter Item Code to update:".
           ACCEPT ITEM-CODE-SEARCH.
               PERFORM VARYING ITEM-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL ITEM-FOUND = 'Y' OR ITEM-INDEX > NUM-OF-PRODUCTS
           IF ITEM-CODE-SEARCH = ITEM-CODE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
            DISPLAY "Enter New Name:".
            ACCEPT NEW-NAME.
            DISPLAY "Enter New Price:".
            ACCEPT NEW-PRICE.
            DISPLAY "Enter New Quantity:".
            ACCEPT NEW-QUANTITY.
            MOVE NEW-NAME TO NAME-LIST(ITEM-INDEX).
            MOVE NEW-PRICE TO PRICE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX).
            MOVE NEW-QUANTITY TO QUANTITY-LIST(ITEM-INDEX).
            DISPLAY "Product Updated."
            MOVE 'Y' TO ITEM-FOUND
           END-IF
       END-PERFORM
           IF ITEM-FOUND = 'N'
               DISPLAY "Product not found."
           END-IF.
    
       DELETE-PRODUCT.
           DISPLAY "Enter Item Code to delete:".
           ACCEPT DEL-ITEM-CODE.
           PERFORM VARYING ITEM-INDEX FROM 1 BY 1
               UNTIL ITEM-FOUND = 'Y' OR ITEM-INDEX > NUM-OF-PRODUCTS
               IF DEL-ITEM-CODE = ITEM-CODE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
                   MOVE SPACES TO ITEM-CODE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
                   MOVE SPACES TO NAME-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
                   MOVE 0 TO PRICE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
                   MOVE 0 TO QUANTITY-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
                   DISPLAY "Product Deleted."
                   SUBTRACT 1 FROM NUM-OF-PRODUCTS
                   MOVE 'Y' TO ITEM-FOUND
           END-IF
           END-PERFORM.
           IF ITEM-FOUND = 'N'
               DISPLAY "Product not found."
           END-IF.

I am confused at to why it's giving me an issue there and not the other instances as the program works when taking out the update-products and WHEN '3' PERFORM UPDATE-PRODUCT.

Your program is very difficult to follow because your indentation is inconsistent and almost completely random. If you indented it properly, you might be able to see the cause of the problem yourself.

An IF statement is terminated by either an END-IF explicit scope terminator or a full-stop (a period, ".").
An inline PERFORM statement is terminated by either an END-PERFORM explicit scope terminator or a full-stop (a period, ".").
The inline PERFORM in paragraph UPDATE-PRODUCT contains an IF statement which is terminated by the full-stop following DISPLAY "Enter New Name:".  I suspect this full-stop also terminates the inline PERFORM.
The remaining statements up until the END-IF are syntactically correct, but the END-IF is a surprise to the compiler because the IF statement has already been terminated.  The END-PERFORM is also a surprise to the compiler because the PERFORM has already been terminated.
A common coding style is to only code full-stops in the Procedure Division to terminate labels (paragraph and section names) and the paragraphs and sections themselves, always using explicit scope terminators such as END-IF and END-PERFORM to terminate COBOL verbs.

"syntax error, unexpected END-IF." - is due to the period/periods "." placed inside the IF statement. The compiler treats the IF as terminated already by the period, so the END-IF is now a syntax error because of the missing IF on the statement.
IF ITEM-CODE-SEARCH = ITEM-CODE-LIST(ITEM-INDEX)
DISPLAY "Enter New Name:".
